# prove a graph has strongly connected vertex

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

We have a directed graph G where X is some vertex. For some vertex called S in graph G, if S has a path from X, it's also true that X has a path from S or $ X \leftrightarrow S$. Write a solution that shows any directed graph has atleast 1 vertex that satisfies these conditions.

What I don't understand is isn't it possible to have a directed graph with vertices that are not strongly connected? i.e. we can draw a graph such that there is a directed path from X to S but not from S to X which would make them reachable but not strongly connected? Would this still be defined as a directed graph or a DAG? Any tips or solutions on how to tackle this problem as I am genuinely lost. Thanks.

EDIT:

To clear it up this is what I meant;

Every digraph  has a vertex X such that for any vertex S in the graph S, if there is a path from X to S , then there is a path from S to X. So $ X \leftrightarrow S$.

Comment: First of all, "strongly connected vertex" is not a standard term. *Graphs* can be strongly connected, not vertices. Second, consider that one option for a vertex that satisfies these conditions is a vertex $x$ such that there are no paths from $x$ to any other vertices at all - then "for every vertex $s$ with a path from $x$" translates to "for every vertex $s$ that is $x$".

Comment: Something in this question is missing and needs to be clarified, because there are extremely simple directed graphs that give counterexamples, as I am sure you could discover yourself.

Comment: @LeeMosher No, it is a true statement, you are just not carefully reading the condition.

Comment: Huh... I read it again and it's false to me. Perhaps the sentence structure is throwing me off.

Comment: @LeeMosher I read it as "Every digraph $G$ has a vertex $x$ such that for all vertices $s$, if there is a path from $x$ to $s$, then there is a path from $s$ to $x$."

Comment: Okay, but why is that not falsified by a directed graph $G$ with two vertices $x$ and $s$ and one directed edge, that edge pointing from $x$ to $s$? Granted, the OP is careless with terminology and perhaps is referring to undirected paths...

Comment: @LeeMosher "$x$" is a variable name, not a designated vertex of $G$. (Otherwise, an easier way to falsify it is with a directed graph where none of the vertices are labeled $x$.) If there are two vertices and a path pointing from one to the other, we pick the second vertex to be $x$.

Comment: Well, I'll wait to see if this question can be written with more care taken with terminology and with quantification of the variables... but at this point it's a rather unclear question. I took $X$ be a a clearly designated vertex in the first sentence.

Comment: @MishaLavrov  I meant strong connectivity or that 2 vertices have transitive, reflexive and symmetric properties. I am basically asking if a directed graph does not contain a cycle then is it still considered a directed graph or a DAG? And how do we go about proving that there exists atleast 1 vertex in a directed graph such that it has a path to another vertex and vice versa.

Comment: @andydandy A DAG is a special kind of directed graph - just like a square is still a rectangle. Anyway, I think you see from the comments above that the quantifiers in your question have to be cleared up, because two of us disagree on what we think it means, and what you're writing in your comment seems to be yet a third interpretation.

Comment: @MishaLavrov my apologies I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

First, to clarify some terminology:

- A directed graph can be *strongly connected* if there is a path from every vertex to every other vertex. We can also define *strongly connected components* of a graph to be maximal subgraphs that are strongly connected. It is not correct to talk about a "strongly connected vertex". (The closest reasonable thing to this is "a vertex that is its own strongly connected component", which is *not* what we want in this problem.)
- A directed graph is *acyclic* if it has no cycles; a directed acyclic graph is called a *dag*. All dags are directed graphs, but not all directed graphs are dags.

In this problem, we want to show that every directed graph has a vertex $x$ such that for all other vertices $s$, *if* there is a path from $x$ to $s$, then there is also a path from $s$ back to $x$. As a special case:

- If a directed graph is strongly connected, then any vertex in the graph can be picked to be $x$, because all possible paths we might want exist.
- If a directed graph is acyclic, then we cannot have nontrivial instances of paths going from $x$ to $s$ and from $s$ back to $x$; that would be a cycle. What we are looking for is a vertex $x$ such that there is no path from $x$ to any other vertex $s \ne x$; then the condition is satisfied trivially. (Exercise: every dag contains at least one such vertex.)

There is an important interaction between the two definitions at the beginning of this answer. For any directed graph $G$, we can define its *condensation* to be the directed graph $H$ whose vertices are the strongly connected components of $G$; for every pair of strongly connected components with some edge from one to the other, there is an edge in $H$. This is illustrated well on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component#Definitions); I am borrowing [that image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component#/media/File:Graph_Condensation.svg) to use below:

[image]

This can be used to solve the problem in general. Given a directed graph $G$, first find its condensation $H$; $H$ will always be acyclic, and there will always be a vertex in $H$ with no edges to any other vertex in $H$. That vertex corresponds to a set $X$ of vertices in $G$; check that every vertex $x \in X$ satisfies the condition we want.

It is also possible to solve the problem without using the language of condensations, though I think that language sheds some light on what is going on. Pick any vertex $x$ for which *the set of vertices reachable from $x$ is as small as possible*, and prove that such a vertex $x$ satisfies the condition we want.

Comment: I don’t understand how the set of X is the set of vertices we want if essentially X is a set of sink vertices?

Comment: Any vertex in $X$ can be the vertex we want. If $s$ is reachable from $x \in X$, then $s \in X$ as well, and so $x$ is reachable from $s$.